# PostgreSQL: error REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW

Tags: postgresql

I ran into a problem when trying

REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW

is owned by the role/user that I am trying to refresh.

But I get an error - *must be owner of materialized view*.

I can't understand why this is happening

I double-checked all grants, role accesses

Comment: Make sure you're on the right user and looking at the right matview `select schemaname,matviewname,matviewowner,current_user from pg_matviews where matviewname ilike '%your_materialized_view_name%';` If there's a materialized view in a schema named after your username, with default `search_path` setting it will be checked before the one in schema `public`. If you're using double-quoted object names, make sure you watch the capitalisation. Without double quotes, remember the names will be folded to lowercase, unless your IDE/client/ORM inserts double-quotes.

Comment: This cannot be. You must be making some mistake.